Citus: Parallel worker not launching
We are performing Citus benchmarking and came across a situation where the planner makes the parallel execution plan but during the execution no parallel workers are launched. The cluster has 3 worker nodes each with 2CPUs running on Centos. What can be the reason behind this?
->  Finalize Aggregate  (cost=76650.31..76650.32 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=174741.832..174741.999 rows=1 loops=1)
                 ->  Gather  (cost=76650.09..76650.30 rows=2 width=32) (actual time=174741.807..174741.974 rows=1 loops=1)
                       Workers Planned: 2
                       Workers Launched: 0
                       ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=75650.09..75650.10 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=174740.490..174740.492 rows=1 loops=

Query we are using for benchmarking is
select sum(amount) from tab_dist_1 where id>=49820 and id<=59743292;


There are two possible reasons:

There are already max_parallel_workers running when your query starts executing, so no more parallel worker slots are available.  There could also be other background processes running; the total limit for all background processes is max_worker_processes.

You execute the query using the JDBC driver, and you (or some tool you are using) uses setMaxRows() to limit the number of result rows, which disables parallel query at execution time. See this article for details.



It's resolved when I performed a full vacuum on the table and reconnected and I was using psql client. Does psql client uses setMaxRows() also I am not sure of max_parallel_workers

setMaxRows() is a JDBC method, so psql doesn't use that. VACUUM (FULL) cannot solve the problem directly, but perhaps rewriting the table made your queries efficient enough that PostgreSQL didn't plan any parallel workers for them.

I came across same problem today and vacuum couldn't help. Then I noticed bunch of logical replication workers which is there to rebalance shards after adding new worker. Then I tried increasing max_worker_processes and it is resolved, the problem was indeed related to that. Thanks very much for the help.

Thanks for the feedback. In that case, the limit is max_worker_processes.
